# how to hide inner columns of the grid retaining the dataIndex

Tags: extjs, grid

I am doing something using ExtJS grid.What actually I need is I want to know how to hide inner columns of the grid header retaining the dataIndex. Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

You could try just hiding a column :

```
myGrid.getColumnModel().setHidden(indexOfColumn, true);
```

Another way : If you wanted to hide the first column you can try this :

```
myGrid.columns[0].setVisible(false);
```

Look at this post :

[ExtJs 4: How do I hide/show grid columns on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791685/extjs-4-how-do-i-hide-show-grid-columns-on-the-fly)

Comment: While I was trying to call myGridName.getColumnModel(),I am getting an error like this."TypeError: undefined is not a function".

Comment: put in working example in JSFiddle and i can have a look at it