# ExtJs 4 : hide/show grid columns with grid that uses ArrayStore

Tags: extjs

ExtJs 4 :
How can I dynamically show and hide columns of a grid that is using an ArrayStore as its store?
I have found this solution
[ExtJs 4: How do I hide/show grid columns on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791685/extjs-4-how-do-i-hide-show-grid-columns-on-the-fly)
I know the setVisible(true | false) for each column is required, but when I ask for grid.columns I get an array of **Objects**, and as Objects they don't have the setVisible function.
If I use Ext.getCmp(..) for each specific column using the column's id then I am getting back a **Column** object and I'm able to get access to the SetVisible function.. but is it also possible to get an array of these Column objects from the grid?

Answer (score 0):

You can find more here http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column

You can use show() and hide() methods

```
 grid.columns[index].show();
```

or absolutely you can use setVisible() methods;

```
 grid.columns[index].setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution in [ExtJs 4: How do I hide/show grid columns on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791685/extjs-4-how-do-i-hide-show-grid-columns-on-the-fly) should work for you. What exact version of ExtJS are you using?

When using **grid.columns** the array of objects you get returned are Column objects. Therefore the following code (as detailed in the linked answer) should work.

```
grid.columns[0].setVisible(false);
```

Check out this [GridPanel Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/oc8) for a live example.

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing something like this:

```
var myGrid = Ext.getCmp("Your_GRID");
var cols = myGrid.columns;
//index of the column to hide.
cols[index].setVisible(!cols[index].isVisible())
```

Here is my working example in fiddle:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/oca

Comment: That's strange, it's exactly what I did, but Chrome says that "setVisible" is not a function and Developer Tools display col to me as "Object". Regardless of that, do you know if it's possible to resize the grid's width after hide/show so it will fit the number of columns being displayed?

Comment: Thats strange the ext version that i made a fiddle is using 4.2.0 are you using an old version ... but I think that this must be their in older versions too.
I have also updated my fiddle(https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/oca) such that the columns resize it self when a column is hidden. This is achieved with help of [flex](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-flex)